# Default DataGridComboBoxColumn ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

Without bothering you with what I intend to do, could someone kindly point out where I can get the default DataGridComboBoxColumn ControlTemplate. I am sure there must be a Control Template or some kind of style that targets a DataGridComboBoxColumn, otherwise how did Microsoft build the DataGridComboBoxColumn.

Answer (score 2):

> Without bothering you with what I intend to do

I think it is not so unimportant, because of these advises on MSDN page [DataGridComboBoxColumn Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcomboboxcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Represents a DataGrid column that **hosts ComboBox controls** in its
>   cells.

and

> If you want to use other controls in your DataGrid, you can create
>   your own column types by using DataGridTemplateColumn.

For styling (also `ControlTemplate`!) of `ComboBox` you can use `ElementStyle` and `EditingElementStyle` properties of `DataGridComboBoxColumn`.

Default template for ComboBox you can find here: [ComboBox Styles and Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/combobox-styles-and-templates)

Small example:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <TextBlock Text={Binding SomePropertyOfYourRowDataContext}/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
```

Comment: Actually what I want to achieve is what I have asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49405667/datagrid-in-combobox-controltemplate-not-working-as-elementstyle

Answer (score 1):

> Could someone kindly point out where I can get the default `DataGridComboBoxColumn` `ControlTemplate`.

A `DataGridComboBoxColumn` is not a `Control` and hence it has no `ControlTemplate`.

It creates a `ComboBox` in its `GenerateEditingElement` method and it is this `ComboBox` that you see when the cell of a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` is in edit mode: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/DataGridComboBoxColumn.cs,90924e66a85fbfa4.